# How can I delete my iOS enterprise app on a certain user's iPhone

Tags: iphone, enterprise

I'm developing a iOS based enterprise app. The client is going to install the app on their employees' personal iPhones. So while an employee leaves the company, the company would have a very strong desire to delete the app on his/her iPhone.

We are going to buy the $299 enterprise license and we have that employee's UDID. I thought I saw somewhere that we can make it by making changes to the mobile provision, but I can'd find it out.

So any ideals?

**Update**
I found this in Apple's [Enterprise Deployment Guide](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Enterprise_Deployment_Guide.pdf) page 66:

"Disabling an Enterprise Application

If you need to disable an in-house application, you can do so by revoking the identity
used to sign the distribution provisioning profile. The application will no longer be able
to be installed, and if it’s already installed, it will no longer open."

I believe that means I can disable the app on every device by revoking the com.companyname.productname thing, but I found no info in the file about how to disable some certain user.

Comment: @Simon, welcome to Beijing and work with us, lol

Comment: Thanks for the invite. I am packing up my things :)

Comment: @Zhao, is Simon your boss? :P

Comment: @Nideo, I don't think so... But I think I should show this question to my boss, as your guys are so interested in him

Comment: @All, damn - could be really funny!

Comment: This article is more pertinent now. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would suggest is to make the user enter his id-number (social-security number or something in USA) and then every time the app opens, query an online database with all the user's id's etc. (Automatically/behind the scenes) As soon as he left the company, remove him from the DB. The app will then only go to a static page and do nothing (maybe display a company logo). This way the app becomes unusable after you remove him from your online database.

Regarding physically deleting the app of his phone, I have no idea if that could be done or will be allowed. If you could delete the app from within itself, then it would also need to query a database.

Comment: we do have stored user's UDIDs on a DB, and the app will only have a main menu if the UDID were deleted. But my boss has some sort of sick on protecting his Intellectual Property. And I think I it on some Enterprise Deploying guide, but I can't find that PDF back...

Comment: I would never in a million years give my SSN to an iOS App.

Comment: @Vcsjones, Me neither, BUT: your not the one giving it (in this case) - your employer will be doing that, without you even knowing.